# How to use phone's Wifi tethering to demonstrate security vulnerabilities on phones

Tags: wifi, android

I am teaching a course to highschool students about computers, and I wanted to do something different for tomorrow class. I was thinking to teach them about wifi security vulnerabilities through a demonstration.

Basically I will create an unprotected network and ask them to connect, then I will hack their phone somehow, don't know exactly how.

Was wondering if you can recommend any methods to do this? I have an unrooted android phone to use and a PC as well in class.

I know this sounds dodgy but I promise you that it's for educational purposes only!

Comment: Mneh. A class that should have been spent on maths...

Comment: I see you also posted this on [android.se]. Cross posting is generally considered undesirable on the StackExchange family of sites. The general topic you're asking about, penetration testing, is on-topic here, but your question is unfortunately much too broad. Offensive Security is a pretty big topic, and unfortunately the answer you're looking for will have to cover more than is appropriate for a single question.

Comment: You might want to look through the [tag:penetration-test] tag. I don't think we have gobs of mobile device hacking in there, but it should hopefully give you a better idea on how to get started. Then you can either fix this up to be more specific or start filling us up on mobile device hacking.

Comment: @ScottPack This is probably the wrong place to ask this question, I was looking for something to show a quick example, thought maybe someone knew an app for that. My bad

Comment: @Michael: No worries. The StackExchange family of sites have a bit of a different goal than your typical forum. You can get a better idea of what we're about by looking at the [FAQ], or how the site works at http://security.stackexchange.com/about. It's not that you asked a *bad* question, just one that's singularly too **big** for our format.

Answer (score 2):

If by "hack their phone" you actually mean "hack their phone", then *no*, this is a very bad idea that could cost you your job (or worse).

But you could so something simpler, such as demonstrate the fundamentals behind a MITM attack using proxy redirection. There's the classic [flip all images upside-down](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) example that comes to mind.

Doing this on your cell phone would be a bit more difficult. Not impossible, but you'd need to get the proxy and image manipulation software installed, which requires a bit more background knowledge than most people have. And of course you'd need to do be able to get the custom firewall redirection rules set up, so again, you'd really have to know your way around Linux, and in particular, Linux on Android. So if you have to ask "how", then this isn't for you. So, the chances of pulling it off by  tomorrow: not so hot.

Comment: Got it. I actually understand most of the topics you are talking about, and the flip-image trick would be a very good one to show the students. I understand that there's no easy way or an app that does that... in that case, I would have to think of something else. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you're allowed then you can use [zANTI2](https://www.zimperium.com/zanti-mobile-penetration-testing). It already comes with an image replacement function so it's useful if you're doing a demonstration about MITM attacks.